# How to specialize a mesh class?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how a mesh class could be specialized ? For example, if we have a Mesh class composed with Polygons from a Polygon class. How can we specialize the mesh to support scalar fields, vector fields, both etc. depending on the application. Maybe for a highly complex simulation we would like 3 scalar fields and 4 vector fields. On the opposite, for simple simulation, we just want one scalar field and that's all.

So by specialization, I mean adding attributes to polygons in order to store local quantities.

It's an open question, I don't know how to do that. It may be impossible like that. But c++ is flexible and every solution allowing to do something close in practice would be helpful.

Comment: do you mean scalar fields per vertex of a single polygon, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that each polygon would store a value (typically a double to store a scalar, three double to store a vector etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You could use templates (assuming that polygons are a collection of vertices, and meshes are a collection of polygons). Here is simply example:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Vector {
  T x, y, z;
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Polygon {
  std::array<T, N> vertices;
};

template <typename T>
struct Mesh {
  std::vector<T> polygons;
};

int main() {
  // mesh with polygons of float-vertices with 3 dimensions
  Mesh<Polygon<Vector<float>, 3>> mesh;

  mesh.polygons.push_back(
      {{{{1.f, 2.f, 3.f}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}, {1.f, 2.f, 3.f}}}});
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer ! But I'm not sure to understand. Your code create a geometrical mesh right ? In your case, a mesh containing 1 polygon with 3 vertices (so a triangle) in 3D. Now how to adapt your code to be able in your main function to add an additional vector to this polygon to store for example velocity for a CFD simulation ? Or a scalar to store temperature ? Or both ?

Comment: OK I got you wrong then. What you want is some kind of generic storage for a dynamic number of properties (that are known at runtime only). Is this correct?

Comment: That's it ! That could be at compile time, because I know at compile time what kind of simulation I do : if I look for a temperature field I need a scalar field and if I look for velocity I need a vector field. But that's it, I want to choose the storage of my mesh.

Comment: when you know them at compile-time, why don't you just add them as members to a specific class?

Comment: That's because I have now several codes and I would like to use the same Mesh classes for all.